# pushChannel is always null (push notification) in windows phone 8.1 devices

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, mpns

```
pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);
```

but it returns me `null` every time I run the application.

It is giving `null` in windows phone 8.1 devices only in wp8 it is registering the channel.

Answer (score 0):

If it is returning push channel as "null", then did you try creating a push channel?

```
// The name of our push channel.
    string channelName = "ToastSampleChannel";

    InitializeComponent();

    // Try to find the push channel.
    pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

    // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
    if (pushChannel == null)
    {
    ######################################################################
        pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);  <---- Create a channel if it doesn't exist
    ######################################################################
        // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
        pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
        pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

        // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
        pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

        pushChannel.Open();

        // Bind this new channel for toast events.
        pushChannel.BindToShellToast();

    }
    else
    {
        // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
        pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
        pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

        // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
        pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

        // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
            pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));

    }
```

Comment: yes this is the only code by microsoft that i used.actually this code is perfectly on wp8 devices but in wp8.1 devices the pushchennel is always null.

Comment: @umashankar I can confirm that the same code works on WP8.1 I am also using it. Check if Notifications are disabled in your Phone's settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
 PushNotificationChannel channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

Debug.WriteLine("Channel :: " + channel.Uri.ToString());